# How to use webpack or browserify to deal with public variables and functions

Tags: javascript, browserify, webpack

I was going to develop a library of components and try to use packing tool JS to achieve modular and each module may use some public variables and functions, such as the following variables, in each module may use, do not know how to configure in browserify or webpack

Project structure

[image]

src/Utils.js - public function

```
//public variable
var userAgent = navigator.userAgent;
var isWebkit = /webkit|khtml/i.test(userAgent);

//global.isWebkit = isWebkit;//not suitable for entry to the global, window pollution
```

src/core/ClassA.js - module A

```
document.write('isWebkit - ' + isWebkit); //module class need access to public variables and functions
function ClassA(options){
    if(isWebkit){

    }
}
module.exports = ClassA;
```

src/Index.js - entry class

```
'use strict';

require('./Utils');

var $ = {
    version: '0.1'
};

$.A = require('./core/ClassA');

module.exports = $;
```

webpack config
bin/build_by_webpack.js

```
var webpack = require("webpack");
webpack({
    entry: {
        'Q': "../src",
    },
    output: {
        path: '../',
        filename: "[name].bundle.js",
        library: 'Q',
    }
}, function (err, stats) {
});
```

bin/build_by_browserify.js

```
var browserify = require('browserify');
var fs = require('fs');

var options = {
    entries: ['../src'],
    standalone: 'Q',
}
var b = browserify(options);
b.bundle().pipe(fs.createWriteStream('../Q.bundle.js'));
```

test.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <script src="Q.bundle.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

Q.bundle.js

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just import your Utils.js in the ClassA to use it

Comment: just require('Utils'); ?

Comment: yes. at the beginning of your ClassA.js file and then use it in your class

Comment: You may have misunderstood what I mean, I want to create a class library, you can try my test program.

Answer (score 0):

I did understand right I meant require Utils from ClassA not from index :

**Utils.js**

```
var userAgent = navigator.userAgent;

module.exports = {
    isWebkit: /webkit|khtml/i.test(userAgent)
}
```

**ClassA.js**

```
var isWebkit = require('../Utils').isWebkit;

document.write('isWebkit - ' + isWebkit); 
function ClassA(options){
    if(isWebkit){
        // do some crazy stuff
    }
}
module.exports = ClassA;
```

It works for me

Comment: As a module to load I know, this is no difference with ordinary module loading, but I hope to direct global access

Answer (score 0):

I will add the global class to this location, so that all the modules can be accessed and browserify configured as follows:

```
var browserify = require('browserify');
var fs = require('fs');
var UglifyJS = require("uglify-js");
var stream = require('stream');
var util = require('util');

function StringStream() {
    stream.Stream.call(this);
    this.writable = true;
    this.buffer = "";
};
util.inherits(StringStream, stream.Stream);

StringStream.prototype.write = function(data) {
    if (data && data.length)
        this.buffer += data.toString();
};

StringStream.prototype.end = function(data) {
    this.write(data);
    this.emit('end');
};

StringStream.prototype.toString = function() {
    return this.buffer;
};

var s = new StringStream();
s.on('end', function() {
    onfinish(this.toString());
});


var fileName = '../Q.bundle.js';
var minFileName = '../Q.bundle.min.js';
var globalName = '../src/Utils.js';

function onfinish(str){
    var index = str.indexOf('var define,module,exports;');
    var str1 = str.substring(0, index);
    var str2 = str.substring(index);

    var globalJS = fs.readFileSync(globalName, 'utf8');

    var string = str1 + '\n' + globalJS + '\n' + str2;
    fs.writeFile(fileName, string);

    var result = UglifyJS.minify(string, {
        fromString : true
    });
    fs.writeFile(minFileName, result.code);
}

var options = {
    entries: ['../src'],
    standalone: 'Q',
}
var b = browserify(options);

b.bundle().pipe(s);
```

output

[image]